# Nightwatchjs - Extracting value from globals file

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

I'm using nightwatchjs (v3.x) to run my test scripts, and I've just introduced some `before` and `beforeEach` hooks to help with these tests.

So, in my `globals.js` file I have the following code (which is using solr-client to get info from a solr instance to be used in subsequent test scripts);

```
var featuresSection = 'features/';
var tipsSection = 'tips-and-tuition/';

// solr reviews query 
var cmsRandomEquipmentReview = require('/nightwatch/custom-commands/solrQuery/randomSolrEquipmentReview');
var cmsEquipmentSettingsPage;
var solr = require('solr-client');

module.exports = {
  before: function(done) {
    var solrClient = browser.globals.solrWpEquipmentReviewsClient;
             equipmentReview.solr_equipment_review_entry(solrClient, function(err,cmsEquipmentSettings) {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
    done(err);
  } else {
     cmsEquipmentSettingsPage = cmsEquipmentSettings;
   //  console.log(cmsEquipmentSettingsPage)
  }
});
 done();
},
```

This solr query is working OK (if I add a `console.log` into this it correctly displays the solr entry).

However, what I now need to do is reference the value of `cmsEquipmentSettingsPage` in my test scripts.

To check that the test was getting the `globals.js` info,  in my test script I added this;

```
module.exports = {
  'Testing the solr query': function (browser) {
    var tipsDisplayed = browser.globals.tipsSection
    var solrQueryDisplayed = browser.globals.cmsEquipmentSettingsPage  
    console.log(tipsDisplayed)
    console.log(solrQueryDisplayed)
},
```

However, when I run my test, `tipsDisplayed` correctly displays `tips-and-tuition/` but `solrQueryDisplayed` displays `undefined`.

This is despite the fact that `cmsEquipmentSettingsPage` definitely has valid values when I add the `console.log` within my `globals.js` file.

Am I doing something obviously wrong with referencing this `cmsEquipmentSettingsPage` value within my test script (i.e. am I 'calling' `cmsEquipmentSettingsPage` before it's actually got a value, or is it something more fundamental?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with the globals values not persisting.

This worked for me;

```
var featuresSection = 'features/';
var tipsSection = 'tips-and-tuition/';

// solr reviews query 
var cmsRandomEquipmentReview = require('/nightwatch/custom-commands/solrQuery/randomSolrEquipmentReview');
var cmsEquipmentSettingsPage = {};
var solr = require('solr-client');

module.exports = {
  cmsEquipmentSettingsPage:cmsEquipmentSettingsPage,
  before: function(done) {
    var solrClient = browser.globals.solrWpEquipmentReviewsClient;
             equipmentReview.solr_equipment_review_entry(solrClient, function(err,cmsEquipmentSettings) {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
    done(err);
  } else {
    cmsEquipmentSettingsPage['setting'] = cmsEquipmentSettings;
   done();
  }
});
},
```

In my `nightwatch.conf.js` file I had to set;
`persist_globals: true,`

And in my test script;

```
it('Globals displayed', async function (browser) {
    console.log(browser.globals.cmsEquipmentSettingsPage)
    })
```

Although this worked, it must be noted that it will only work in serial working. There is a bug raised for globals persisting in Parallel working.